# How can i implement offline Wikipedia in android?

Tags: android, offline, wikipedia-api

I want to make offline Wikipedia android application. For that i searched the Google for database samples but till now i didn't find any database.Is there any SQLite database related to android Wikipedia .

The problem here is how can i download offline Wikipedia database? And how to read that in the android?

I try with the .deb extension database but i can't read that database. So can i get any way to do such type of app in android or any thing related to that.

Thanks in advance

Shankararao Pilli

Comment: And the problem is that, Wikipedia is constantly updated with latest news and many new pages are added daily. Most of data in your app might get obsolete soon.

Comment: Not a matter for obsolete but I have to display data offline with some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Wikipedia Database out there , but there is a [MediaWiki's API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) which you can use to fetching your data and store it on your db to access later offline.